# In R, how do I get a loop function to work on unique sites where a site_id is present in every row?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to make a loop of code where I make yearly averages over time for each site (lake in this case). I have the following (subset of my) data:

```
 SITE    YEAR   ANC   DOC    NO3    SBC_ALL  SBC.Na   SO4
 1434021 1996 -25.318 2.439 18.701  91.327  79.580  99.695
 020059O 2012  70.010 8.070  2.750 147.270 186.350  45.540
 1434021 1997 -22.534 2.387 21.617  96.635  84.946 102.071
 1434025 1994  25.352 1.595 15.334 172.988 159.256 117.223
 020059O 2003  48.140 7.860  4.410 156.010 188.340  78.000
 020059O 1993  28.230 7.430  3.420 139.540 181.590  84.550
 1364959 1993   6.050 0.756 19.111 148.300 131.157 118.411
 1434021 2008  -4.386 2.420 13.861  80.651  70.136  82.469
 143400680 1996 -20.842 4.961 16.075  99.999  88.871  88.057
 1364959 1997   2.650 1.845 25.613 143.504 126.480 104.679
```

I run the following code and get graphs for **each** row of data. I want to get graphs just for each specific site (for example SITE = 020059O). Each site has an annual average for each year from 1990 to 2017.

```
for (site_id in mydata$SITE)
{ 
p <-
 filter(mydata, SITE == site_id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = ANC)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle(site_id)
print(p)
}
```

This code produces:

[Example of yearly ANC at site 020059O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66y2W.png)

I've looked into using a distinct() or unique() function, but these seem to remove duplicates. I need duplicates in the data because they contain the year and the average for that year. What other options do I have to only run ggplot on the unique SITE, but keeps the yearly data that I need?

Original idea for loop code came from: http://www.r-gators.com/2017/10/25/loops-in-r/

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of your data using dput

Comment: You may be interested in facetting your plots, i.e. breaking your plot into subplots for each site_id. This is as easy as doing `ggplot(...) + ... + facet_wrap(~SITE)`, without any loop.

Comment: @antoine-sac I thought about doing this as well. We have 139 sites in total (I reduced the data here for simplicity), so this would make it a bit congested. We could use this for when we are creating graphs for a subset of our data though! Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (site_id in unique(mydata$SITE))
  { 
    p <- filter(mydata, SITE == site_id) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = ANC)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      theme_bw() +
      ggtitle(site_id)
      print(p)
  }
```

This only removes duplicates from the list of IDs to loop through - you will still get multiple rows in your output.

Comment: That did the trick! I was thinking using the unique in the for statement would prevent it from using all the YEAR data. But that makes sense it still uses the all of the YEAR rows/data in the ggplot section of the code.